# How to make a DB connection available anywhere in sinatra without using globals?

Tags: ruby, database, sinatra, global-variables

Currently I have something like:

```
$db = Db::Connection.new()
```

then I use it like so:

```
get '/foo' do
 response.body = $db.fetch(params["bar"]) || ""
end
```

I was told by someone here on SO that this is not optimal.

Why and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

In my `configure do` block I would put it in settings like this:

```
set :db, Db::Connection.new()
```

Then when you need it, get it thusly:

```
settings.db.fetch(params["bar"])
```

Or assign it to a local variable if you need to re-use it etc.